# Install GeyserMC on PaperMC server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am needing help on how to install GeyserMC on my PaperMC server. I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.10, and everything I've tried so far (curling from several Github Repos) has NOT worked on the server startup. Remember, I'm working on a CLI and not a GUI (which is probably the reason I can't find a working tutorial). If someone could show me a curl command for this to work, I'd like it, but any help would work.

Comment: What are the exact commands you use?

Comment: curl -o geyser.jar -L https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser.git
and with a start.sh file for Geyser, the output the server gives me is "[DirectoryProviderSource] Error loading plugin: File 'plugins/Geyser.jar' failed to load!"

Comment: I've since deleted geyser from the plugin folder, so I couldn't show the start.sh, but geyser.jar was having issues. I can elaborate if what I gave wasn't enough.

Comment: Don't you just put the Spigot plugin into the plugins folder?

Comment: I did and it "failed to load". I'll try downloading off of a usb rather than github curling and see if that changes anything.

Comment: ...could just be a case of capitalization? The error says "**G**eyser.jar failed to load" but you're downloading it as "**g**eyser.jar"

Comment: A `.git` URL is for the git command to check out/download the entire repository, for compiling it yourself. That's not a jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Geyser onto Spigot is as easy as installing any plugin. Simply <s>drag it</s> download it straight into your `plugins` folder.

Since Paper is just a fork of Spigot, most Spigot plugins should *just* "work".

---

So `cd` to wherever that plugin folder is first...

Then:

```
curl https://download.geysermc.org/v2/projects/geyser/versions/latest/builds/latest/downloads/spigot -L > Geyser-Spigot.jar
```

And you'll have the plugin in your plugins folder. Just restart your server for the config files to generate.

You can find links to the files on [Geyser's own website](https://geysermc.org/download#spigot).

Comment: The minecraft server or the server itself?

Comment: It works on startup! Now I need floodgate and port forwarding properly enabled.